# Can we modify final variable with parameterized string.format()

Tags: java, string.format

I have a question related to the parameterized string.format() in Java.
Can we modify the final variables through string.format()?
How does it work?

```
private static final String ERROR_SCHEMA_INVALID = "Schema validation failed: %s";
log.error(String.format(ERROR_SCHEMA_INVALID, e.getMessage()));
```

Comment: You can't modify final variables. The code you showed does not modify `ERROR_SCHEMA_INVALID`.

Comment: String.format returns a new string. Strings are immutable in Java

Comment: @Sweeper bit of a bad choice of explanation. In this case we can't modify the final variables, since it's an immutable type, but with most types, we would be able to modify it. We just can't reassign them.

Comment: @Stultuske Mutating an object held by a final variable is not modifying a final variable. The object is not the variable.

Comment: @Stultuske Hmm... I guess we just disagree about terminology here. Modifying a variable and reassigning a variable mean the same thing to me... For mutable/immutable types' distinction, I would say that you can(not) modify/change the _object_.

Comment: @Sweeper that I agree to. Unfortunately, I come all to often in the situation where I have to explain that making a variable final doesn't mean it's state can't change. So I usually go from that perspective. Indeed, it remains the same object, yet it's value not necessarily so.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

1. Variables declared `final` cannot change its reference to another object.
   For example,

```java
final String a = "hi";
a = "bye"; //Compile error
```

2. `String`s are immutable. That means once the string object is instantiated, the characters within cannot be changed.

The String class provides methods for you to work with the string object, but instead of modifying the string object itself, it returns a new string.

**Answer**

The answer is no. There is no way to change an initialized `final` variable to refer to another object (except for reflection).

What is going on with your code, is that

1. You invoke the static method `String.format` and pass in the parameters `ERROR_SCHEMA_INVALID` i.e. `"Schema validation failed: %s"`, and `e.getMessage()`.
2. The method creates a new string similar to `"Schema validation failed: %s"`, except that `%s` is replaced with `e.getMessage()`. (It internally uses a Formatter)
3. The method returns the new string.

The method did not interfere with your variable in any way, and it cannot.

In terms of design, if you want to add "Schema validation failed: " as a prefix to all the error messages related to your program, then it is fine.